# torchaudio C++ extension is not available

Tags: pytorch

Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\extension\extension.py", line 14
warnings.warn('torchaudio C++ extension is not available.')
UserWarning: torchaudio C++ extension is not available.

Can anyone help me with this...

Comment: Which code produces this error ? Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: One of possible examples can be found in "pytorch" section here: https://github.com/snakers4/silero-models. Okay looks like different question but have the same problem